# XMLHttpRequest call returning nothing

Tags: javascript, python, api, xmlhttprequest

I am making a website that needs to make a XMLHttpRequest call to a python script (on a third-party website) when a button on the website is pressed. The python script will then make changes to the data, and return it back to the website.

I have got this working if I make the call to an existing API tester such as this: https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2

However, it doesn't work when I make the call to my own python script hosted on my website.

Here is the code of the python script that is being hosted on my website `https://example.com`:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def testing():
    return jsonify(test="Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

... and here is the code that aims to get data from the above python script.

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

myRequest.open('GET', 'https://example.com');

myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
        alert(myRequest.responseText);
    }
}

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", 
    function() {
        myRequest.send();
    }
);
```

As mentioned, if I use an established API example, such as https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 instead of `https://example.com` then it works correctly, so I'm certain it's an issue with the python script, but I just can't figure out what as there's no error messages.

Comment: See your dev tools in browser what request is being sent and response code. Check if your click handler is being called or not. If it is called, a network call is triggered or not. If a network call is triggered, your server is receiving it or not. Put some logging in your api end point if it is receiving any request or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a CORS issue. When a web page loaded from server A is sending a request (via XMLHttpRequest) to server B, then we are facing a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) scenario. This kind of request has to meet certain requirements (as described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Long story short, server B (here example.com) has to provide an extra header in its response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://server-a-domain.com
```

The following is OK, too. By the way, that's what your example server regres.in returns.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If you are using Flask, then look into Flask-CORS that seems to provide a generic solution: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/